# Login to Freebase for MQLWrite operation

Tags: freebase, mqlwrite

I try to work with Freebase repository. It is possible to make MQLRead request but for this it not necessary to login into repository itself. MQLRead operation is well documented on Freebase wiki site, while no MQLWrite specifications present. Old documentation exists but seems no working for me. Firstly, I can't made www.freebase.com registration with separate login/password because this way is not available - only registration with Google or Yahoo accounts. How to use new Google credentials for Freebase registration? I can get access_token from Google but can't use it for my application. Is it necessary to use cookies for registration as old documentation said? or not? And which URL I should use for registration: http://api.sandbox-freebase.com/api/account/login or https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1-sandbox or something else?

I know that Google Refine project can use Freebase as a repository and it can write data to Freebase, but for me it take a time to find a way how it work.

Please, help me!

Comment: I have the same problem, no solution so far... They seem to ask (in http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2012-April/008844.html this mail) to contact one of their employees for access to the write API.

Answer (score 2):

The write service has not yet been ported to the new API, and may not be available before the old API is deprecated; see [this mail](http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2012-April/008844.html) from Jason Douglas, one of the Freebase product managers.

Comment: Does this mean that *right now* I can't perform write operations by API, because I don't have plain-freebase account?

Comment: Apparently so :-( I'd suggest mailing the freebase-discuss list and asking what to do.